# Select 3 results from every table

Tags: mysql

Assuming a database with a ridiculous amount of tables (200+), how can I perform `SELECT * FROM <> LIMIT 3;` where `<>` represents all the tables in the database? My goal is to get an idea of what each table contains, and the column names shown in `DESCRIBE` are not particularly useful. Therefore I would like to see 3 records from each table.

I know that I could easily script this in PHP by iterating over the output of `show tables;` however I am looking for a command to run on the MySQL interpreter (`mysql>` prompt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's described in detail under this link (haven't tried it myself though, it's just in my bookmarks):

http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/mysql-clone-of-sp_msforeachtable/624

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `usp_mysql_foreachtable`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_mysql_foreachtable`(IN sql_string VARCHAR(1000))
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Functional clone of sp_MsForEachTable'
    BEGIN

    DECLARE var_tablename VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE last_row BIT;

    DECLARE table_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME
                    FROM information_schema.TABLES
                    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                    AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET last_row = 1;

    OPEN table_cursor;
    FETCH table_cursor INTO var_tablename;

    SET last_row = 0;
    SET @var = '';

    lbl_table_cursor: LOOP

        SET @qry = REPLACE(sql_string, '?', var_tablename);

        PREPARE q FROM @qry;
        EXECUTE q;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE q;

        FETCH table_cursor INTO var_tablename;
        IF last_row = 1 THEN
            LEAVE lbl_table_cursor;
        END IF;
    END LOOP lbl_table_cursor;

    CLOSE table_cursor;

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Then you call it with

```
CALL usp_mysql_foreachtable('SELECT * FROM ? LIMIT 3;');
```

Comment: Thank you! The linked site has some other wonderful articles.